# Movie where a man is abducted by beings believed to be aliens and finds out they were from the future

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, time-travel

What's the title of movie where a man was abducted by beings believed to be aliens and finds out they were from the future. They came back in time because the genetic manipulation in the future affected the diversity and civilization will be condemned because of it. So they came back to abduct people who historically won't have kids.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made? Also, were the time-travellers actually _humans_ from the future? That's what I gathered from what you wrote, but the phrasing is somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: Hi. I watched it on TV, about ten years ago. It was probably produced after the 2000s. Yes, the time travelers were "genetic enhanced"humans, but they didn't look like nowadays humans because of that manipulation.

Comment: Makes me think of the movie made from John Varley's _Millennium_ but it's not really a a match.

Comment: It's not the Millennium movie... I'd like to recommend the movie to some friends, but I can't remember nor the title, nor the cast.

Answer (score 16):

I suspect it is older than you remember (if this is correct).

*[Official Denial](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Official_Denial)*

> Official Denial is a 1993 made-for-television science fiction film about a man who is abducted by aliens. It is eventually revealed that the aliens are in reality humans from the future.

And the timeline does change because the protagonists have a baby at the end.  The full movie is currently on YouTube but below is a commercial.  At the time this was a big deal for the Sci-Fi channel getting into producing NEW content and had the stars of *Buck Rogers* and *Battlestar Galactica*.

Specifically in the full movie at the 1:17:21 mark you can see the discovery of family tree records in the UFO.

Comment: It's this movie, thanks very, very much. I probably watched a rerun.

Comment: @JoaoDias it's a good movie.  Also i see the uploader of the full movie on YouTube is the writer.  He also did an x-files like series dark skies and I see does podcasts on UFOs.  So I'm assuming must believe in the subject or have a way above average level of interest in UFOs.

Comment: This was way more fun than it had any right to be. Thanks for posting the movie link.

Comment: @MadPhysicist another early 1990s Alien Abduction TV event was CBS Channel movie INTRUDERS (1992) - also is on YouTube.

Comment: @Joao Dias - If this answer is correct, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 4):

Could it be *[Beyond the Sky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyond_the_Sky_(film))* (2018)? From [this review](https://www.imdb.com/review/rw4461477/?ref_=tt_urv):

> .... This is where the plot completely goes off the rails. Apparently the aliens are actually humans from the future who have evolved to the point where they "only see logic" and have apparently lost the ability to feel emotions... I guess? After they witness the budding relationship between Emily and Chris, they reveal themselves and explain that they have actively been removing the bad memories from at least the two of them for their whole lives, in order to change their future, or something. In the end it doesn't matter because they send Emily and Chris back to Earth and the movie pretty much ends. There's a time skip "seven years and 9 months"  to the birthday party of Emily and Chris' child, which I suppose is supposed to contrast Chris' bad memory of one of his own birthdays which is highlighted throughout the film (and is one of the memories that the "aliens" partially hid from him).

It's not genetic diversity, but it is future humans abducting contemporary ones, and believed to be aliens.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that lucasbachmann's answer is the correct one, but I will keep mine up as a partial match.

Comment: Half the reason I browse these questions when my [code is compiling](https://xkcd.com/303/) is to find interesting "not quite matching" recommendations. Please keep it up.